# Which jsf component library best suits Liferay portlet application

Tags: jsf, components, ipc, liferay

Could any one throw some light on the following jsf component libraries to be used in Liferay portlet development which supports Inter Portlet Communication (IPC), Ajax Push Support and JSF - Portlet bridge,  community support etc., for Primefaces, Richfaces, Icefaces and Myfaces.

--Velu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my own experience I have to agree with what doc_180 says, among the frameworks you mention ICEFaces is definitely the best choice, but stick to new 2.0+ version as it has many improvements.

A lot can off course also be done by using the same stack as Liferay itself uses in the 6+ version: Struts/MVC-portlet + [AlloyUI](http://alloy.liferay.com/)

Comment: Finally we have decided to use Icefaces 2.0 EE. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

ICEFaces works like a charm with liferay. Especially with ajax push support, its a very good choice.